# How to get matching rows from two tables in SQL, without repeated calls from java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I have to read a set of rows from a table(say A) containing a unique id for each row (say id_value).

Now using this id_value i have to get rows from another table (say B).

i am using java so my code is:

```
ResultSet rs= [ Code to get rows from table A ] ;

while(rs.next())
{
ResultSet rs2= [Code to get rows from table B using the id_value from table A using rs.getString("id_value");]; 
}
```

The above query if ofcourse slow as the number of rows can be more than 500 at a time in table A.

Does anybody knows a better and fast solution to this problem or how to do this in a single query ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on joins in SQL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

You want to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT a.value_1, a.value_2, b.value_1, b.value_2
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
ON a.id_value = b.table_a_id
WHERE a.value_1 = "something"
```

It would be easier to help you if you had actual queries, though.

Comment: Not a fan of the older `TableA,TableB` join syntax. There are just some things you can't do with it that you can with the explicit ansi-92 joins, and for complex queries with several tables it's much less readable.

Comment: But how to read the data from the resultset ??

As the inner inner query i am running is coming from a different table and for each row in table A there is 1 or more data in table B , how to read the data from the result set for each unique id_value ???

Comment: @Lokesh, exactly ths same way except now data from both tables has been correlated into a single row, and you would iterate the set of rows as usual

Answer (score 1):

You could use a left join:

```
  SELECT table1.*, table2.* from table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.table2id
  WHERE table1.ID = 123;
```

Comment: Thanks Joel . I am using a left outer join now and it has really solved the problem.

Comment: @Joel - I see the revision, and it boggled me?

Comment: You had *.table1, *.table2 for your column list, which is just backwards and wouldn't work.  It's also likely that table1 and table2 each have their own IDs columns - a foreign key column in a table is unlikely to be named just "id".

Comment: Is it possible to update on this newly made table and have it update the real table?